# How to reset any given CSS to a control (for sure)?

Tags: html, css

In the early html days the bullet list was one of the first elements. Now I can't get these bullets to appear in my list because of too many CSS rules overruling. How can I force a reset that gives my the bullets back?

I tried

```
<ul style="all:initial;">
<ul style="all:unset;">
```

but no bullets appear.

```
<ul style="all:initial;list-style-type:circle;">
   <li>Para empezar una ....</li>
   <li>La seción caduca automaticamente ...</li>
   <li>Tras 3 intentos seguidos...</li>
</ul>
```

This works if I place them in a new blank aspx page within the form tags and without css refernce, but not in my rather large content page with lots of CSS references.

---

I'm not a css expert -as you notice; the styles I coppied from a masterpage/contentpage template and it is obviously them that don't allow me to get the bullet list I want.

Comment: inline css has the most specificity so it should be the one that's applied. However, if you're CSS stylesheets are riddled with `!important` - this still won't work.

Comment: show your full html

Comment: I don't think that posting the whole code gives more clue. It is very long... a content page with many CSS references.

Comment: @Barnabeck inline css is really really bad practice, everything should be inside a stylesheet. I'm guessing you've now guessed that maintenance and updates are a lot harder to pull-off ...

Comment: Those bullets should appear without adding any styles, you must be hiding from elsewhere

Comment: Apparently this reset only the inheritable values passed down from the parent.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Unfortunately none of them worked for me. No bullets are showing up in the context of my webpage (with master and content page), no matter what I try - not even a tab between the <ul> and the <li> items. If I eliminate all css rules from my stylesheet then the bullets show up, but the question keeps not being answered: Is there a way to force that a rule is applied independently from any prior rules defined in a stylesheet? Doesn't seem to be possible in my case. Btw. there isn't an !important reference in any of the styles. Should I post my stylesheet?

Comment: As we say in Portuguese "you're trying to block the sun with a strainer". You need to understand the CSS rules that are applying and override them, you'll be tempted to use `!important` but that will only make your life harder. You should strive to understand CSS specificity. Also Chrome's dev tools will show you the source of a style (which css declaration); that should tell you enough about how to create a more specific rule

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list-style: initial;`

In the example below, the only reason for the `.classOuter` and `.classInner` is to mock your example of inherited styles.

As you can see, `list-style: initial;` reverts the list except for the first.

```css
.classOuter {
  list-style: none;
}

.classInner {
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  list-style: initial
}
```

```html
<ul class="classOuter">
  <li class="classInner">Para empezar una ....</li>
  <li>La seción caduca automaticamente ...</li>
  <li>Tras 3 intentos seguidos...</li>
</ul>
```

To override that class you need to add the `!important` keyword:

```css
.classOuter {
  list-style: none;
}

.classInner {
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  list-style: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="classOuter">
  <li class="classInner">Para empezar una ....</li>
  <li>La seción caduca automaticamente ...</li>
  <li>Tras 3 intentos seguidos...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in my Website Context. Only if I delete all styles of my stylesheet the normal behavior is regained and the bullets show up.

Comment: Yuck, suggesting `!important`? What you should really do is fix the specificity instead of giving up and using important, which means you're just kicking the bucket down the road. `.classOuter li, ;.classInner li {...}`

Comment: @JuanMendes Would love to, but that implies that you'd direct control over files the files that are doing the styling which is not always the case, like if they were coming from a CDN or something.

Comment: Your example doesn't even have a disclaimer. It does not claim that this should only be done when you're styling over someone else's style. Even those, you can still apply more specificity, you just have to look harder. Fight the urge to give in.